# Version management of gems while working with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

I have been coding in rails3 and have all the dependencies resolved. Now, I have moved back to rails 2 and there are lots of dependency issues. Is there any sane approach to make sure that all the gems and dependencies are resolved automatically based on the current rails version?

I keep getting this error

```
 `default_options': undefined method `write_inheritable_attribute' for  Rails::Generator::Base:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Error Log

```
    from /home/saiesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/rails_generator/base.rb:90:in `<class:Base>'
from /home/saiesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/rails_generator/base.rb:85:in `<module:Generator>'
from /home/saiesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/rails_generator/base.rb:48:in `<module:Rails>'
from /home/saiesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/rails_generator/base.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/saiesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /home/saiesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /home/saiesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/rails_generator.rb:37:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/saiesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /home/saiesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /home/saiesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rails-2.3.8/bin/rails:15:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/saiesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/rails:19:in `load'
from /home/saiesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/rails:19:in `<main>'
from /home/saiesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
from /home/saiesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

Gem List

```
 *** LOCAL GEMS ***
```

> actionmailer (3.2.13, 2.3.12, 2.3.8) 
>   actionpack (3.2.13, 2.3.12, 2.3.8)
>   activemodel (3.2.13)
>   activerecord (3.2.13, 2.3.12, 2.3.8)
>   activeresource (3.2.13, 2.3.12, 2.3.8)
>   activesupport (3.2.13, 2.3.12, 2.3.8)
>   arel (3.0.2)
>   bourbon (3.0.1)
>   builder (3.0.4)
>   bundler (1.3.5)
>   bundler-unload (1.0.1)
>   cancan (1.6.10)
>   coffee-rails (3.2.2)
>   coffee-script (2.2.0)
>   coffee-script-source (1.6.2)
>   commonjs (0.2.6)
>   daemons (1.1.9)
>   delayed_job (3.0.5)
>   delayed_job_active_record (0.4.4)
>   erubis (2.7.0)
>   execjs (1.4.0)
>   formtastic (2.2.1)
>   formtastic-bootstrap
>   (2.1.3)
>   haml (4.0.3)
>   hike (1.2.3)
>   i18n (0.6.1)
>   journey (1.0.4)
>   jquery-rails (3.0.1, 2.3.0)
>   json (1.8.0)
>   kaminari (0.14.1)
>   less (2.3.2)
>   less-rails (2.3.3)
>   less-rails-fontawesome (0.5.0) 
>   libv8 (3.11.8.17 x86-linux)
>   mail (2.5.4)
>   meta_search (1.1.3)
>   mime-types (1.23)
>   multi_json (1.7.7)
>   mysql (2.9.1) 
>   mysql2 (0.3.11)
>   polyamorous (0.5.0)
>   polyglot (0.3.3)
>   rack (1.4.5, 1.1.6)
>   rack-cache (1.2)
>   rack-ssl (1.3.3)
>   rack-test (0.6.2)
>   rails (3.2.13, 2.3.8)
>   railties (3.2.13)
>   rake > (10.1.0, 10.0.4)
>   rdoc (4.0.1, 3.12.2)
>   ref (1.0.5)
>   rubygems-bundler (1.2.0)
>   rvm (1.11.3.8)
>   sass (3.2.9)
>   sass-rails (3.2.6) 
>   sprockets (2.2.2)
>   therubyracer (0.11.4)
>   thor (0.18.1)
>   tilt (1.4.1)
>   treetop (1.4.14)
>   twitter-bootstrap-rails (2.2.7)
>   tzinfo (0.3.37)
>   uglifier (2.1.1)

Comment: can u add the error log n the list of gems u r using?

Comment: Please view my edited question @prasad.surase

Comment: since u r using rails 2, shouldnt u be using ruby 1.8 rather than 1.9.3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not make use of gemsets for each project?

create a file inside your app called `.rvmrc`

```
rvm use --create ruby-x.x.x-version@your_app_name
```

for exemple:

```
rvm use --create ruby-1.9.3-head@your_app_name
```

now when you'll run bundle it will gems to separate folder like in my case:

```
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@your_app_name
```

in this case switching from one app to another will load the needed gemset with gems for your app. It's like using RVM to switch between Ruby versions.